# Can not convert type of model to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make simple application through MVC. Here is my code-

//MODEL

```
 public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int empID { get; set; }
        public Gender genderEmployee { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
```

//VIEW

```
 @using EmployeeTest.Models
    @model EmployeeTest.Models.EmployeeModel

        <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.genderEmployee)
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.genderEmployee,
                            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                            "Select Gender")
                    </div>
         </div>
```

//CONTROLLER

```
 EmployeeInfo objInfo= new EmployeeInfo()
                    {
                        empName = empModel.empName,
                        Gender = empModel.genderEmployee,
                        dateOFBirth = empModel.dateOfBirth,
                        IsActive = empModel.isActive,
                    };
```

I am getting error in controller code which is given below-
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'EmployeeTest.Models.Gender' to 'bool?'**

In database the data type of gender is bit.

Comment: You got the error at the line you give us ? At new EmployeeInfo ? I feel something is missing here.

Comment: Well I did not missed but got the solution by changing code little-
 public enum Gender
    {
        Male=1,
        Female=0
    }

Gender = Convert.ToBoolean (empModel.genderEmployee)

Comment: If you showed the class EmployeeInfo the error would be clear

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `EmployeeInfo` object has a `bool? Gender` property. This is saying you cannot convert the `Gender genderEmployee` into a `bool? Gender`. You will need to replace `Gender = empModel.genderEmployee` with `Gender = (bool?) empModel.genderEmployee`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the model to better align with your database (bit) will work better.  There is no reason to complicate it with an enum.  Try something like this:

```
 public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int empID { get; set; }
        public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    }
```

If you still need to use the enum for other reasons in your view/controller you can do an explicit conversion when assigning the value to the EmployeeInfo()
object.

Answer (score -1):

Little piece of change in code in model and controller solved my issue

```
 public enum Gender
    {
        Male=1,
        Female=0
    }


Gender = Convert.ToBoolean (empModel.genderEmployee)
```

Comment: Unclear how this post relates to the question (as question has no information about `Gender` at all) and generally look like a bad recommendation - why "gender" would ever be boolean value (does "false" means lack of gender?), why one would use such a fragile construct as casting enum to bool?